# Syntax error: Selector "canvas" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id) Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I'm using a `not pure selectors` on my project in a specify file in next.js

[image]

I found this answer that said, that is no possible to use not pure selectors different than `global.css`
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/31705

I was wondering, is possible to use in a different file with some extra configuration

my current version of next.js is `"next": "^13.3.4"`

Comment: Why do you want to use a not pure selector?

Comment: @Konrad because is a template that I downloaded and in this template are using of this way.

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to solve this problem is to assign a module-scoped css class to your top-level element in your component:

```
import styles from "./landing.module.css";

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.landing}>
      <canvas />
    </div>
  );
}
```

After that you can use nested selectors in your css as follows:

```css
.landing canvas {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

2. If your 3rd-party css file is too long to modify by hand, but you want to use it only on a specific page of your app, you can use `sass` (you'll need to install sass with `npm i -D sass`):

```
import styles from "./landing.module.scss"

export default function Landing() {
  return (
    <main className={styles.landing}>
      <canvas />
    </main>
  );
}
```

```css
// landing.module.scss

.landing {
    @import "landing";
}
```

```css
// landing.css

canvas {
    width: 100%;
}
```

3. If your 3rd-party css is truly global css that you intend to use across multiple pages, you can import it in your `_app.tsx`:

```js
import "@/styles/landing.css";
```

Comment: but if I use of this way, I should to update all the files and is a really long file to modify every css

Comment: Are you using `app` or `pages` directory?

Comment: I'm using pages directory

Comment: @FauricioValencia, please see my updated answer. Hopefully, it addresses your use case based on the limited info you provided.